# Face Recognition using HMM

Tags: hidden-markov-models

I had learnt some of the research papers of Face Recognition using Hidden Markov Model.
Can you help me how Hidden Markov model is applied to face recognition?Also can you please give some numerical example?

Comment: I think this is not the appropriate StackExchange for this question. Please consider moving it to Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Regarding your question, the page a the bottom has some detailed information on HMMs for face recognition. Anyhow, you should be aware that HMMs are not the state of the art technique in face recognition and computer vision in general.

https://www.intechopen.com/books/reviews-refinements-and-new-ideas-in-face-recognition/hidden-markov-models-in-automatic-face-recognition-a-review

Comment: In some of the papers, face recognition using HMM gives good accuracy.Can you suggest a concept/algorithm for face recognition?

Comment: Nowadays, face recognition (just like any other computer vision task) is addressed mostly using deep learning, i.e., using deep neural networks. You have a survey that includes most recent works here https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.03524.